# Python + Q (KDB) - which tools are easy to use and well maintained

Tags: python, kdb

From a thread dating a few years back I found some options to integrate python and kdb, namely

- qpt
- Dan's tools
- PyQ
- qPython

The last two seem to be the only ones actively updated at the moment. My question goes to the folks that actually use any (and ideally tried several) of these tools. From your experience, which of the two latter ones is more suitable for me. Selection criteria would be (in that order)

- ease of use (I am new to q, ideally I would do more work in python than in q)
- documentation (seems to be generally not great on anything kdb)
- python 3.x support
- speed

If I completely missed a tool that fits my requirements, please let me know. I am aware of threads that raise similar questions, but I am looking for a 2017 answer, not 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [kdb/python](http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/python-api) guide was updated 2017:

> For anyone else who needs a Python library, I am highly recommending
>   the exxeleron qpython library (though it does require numpy, which
>   requires 2.6 As a minimum, I believe, which can be a limitation)

Comment: Your "kdb/python guide" is incorrect with respect to Python versions supported by [PyQ](https://pyq.enlnt.com).  PyQ supported the 3.x series of Python since its [version 3.0.1](https://pyq.enlnt.com/whatsnew/changelog.html#pyq-3-0-1) which was released in 2012.

Answer (score 4):

Exxeleron's [qPython](https://github.com/exxeleron/qPython) "is a Python library providing support for interprocess communication between Python and kdb+ processes."  While the same functionality is available from [PyQ](https://pyq.enlnt.com), PyQ offers much more than just IPC.

PyQ is a full-featured Python interpreter running inside a kdb+ instance.  For a Python programmer, PyQ gives a direct access to kdb+ data without any need to program in q. For a q programmer, PyQ offers an easy access to a rich set of computational and visualization libraries that Python is famous for.

To give an example, here is a linear interpolation function `inp` written in q:

```
inp:{y[i]+(z-x i)*(deltas[y]%deltas x)1+i:x bin z}
```

It takes three arguments: `x` and `y` are coordinates of the known data points and `z` is x-coordinates of the interpolated values. It returns the  y-coordinates of the interpolated values. The same function can be written in PyQ using pure Python syntax:

```
def inp(x, y, z):
    slope = y.deltas / x.deltas
    i = x.bin(z) 
    return y[i] + (z - x[i]) * slope[i+1]
```

If you prepare the data in q

```
x:0.1*til 10
y:x - x * x
z:5?1f
```

and call either Python or q implementation, you will get the same result.  At the PyQ's Python prompt this can be verified as follows:

```
>>> inp(q.x, q.y, q.z) == q.inp(q.x, q.y, q.z)
True
```

Of course, an experienced Python programmer would not need to write such a function from scratch because NumPy already has [numpy.interp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) which does the same and more. If, as a q programmer, you want to use numpy.interp from q, all you need is a simple wrapper that converts the result to a `K` object before returning it.  This is how it can be done at the `q)` prompt

```
q)p)import numpy; from pyq import q, K
q)p)def inp2(x, y, z): return K(numpy.interp(z, x, y))
q)p)q.inp2 = inp2
```

And now, `inp2` is ready to use:

```
q)inp[x;y;z] ~ inp2(x;y;z)
1b
```

Since PyQ runs inside kdb+, it gets its IPC implementation for free.  For example, I can open a connection to the remote server at port 8888 and ask for its local time in two lines of code:

```
>>> h = q.hopen('::8888')
>>> h('.z.P')
k('2017.07.07D17:15:19.261285000')
```

However, most of the tasks can be accomplished in PyQ without any IPC (or even copying) at all because all your kdb+ data is already in the same process as your Python code.

To cover the OP's rubrics, on the ease of use, qPython being a pure Python library may be easier to install, but PyQ programing is often easier because it does not require a separate kdb+ server.  [PyQ documentation](https://pyq.enlnt.com/manual/pyq.html) is comparable in quality to that of [qPython](http://qpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest).  PyQ offered python 3.x support since its version 3.0.1 and Python 3.1.  Currently (2017) it is actively tested with Python 2.7, 3.5 and 3.6.  Speed comparison would not be fair because PyQ has direct access to kdb+ data and does not require IPC, so it can accomplish many tasks 100x faster than qPython.

Disclaimer: I am the author of PyQ.

Comment: you may want to request the supported version for PyQ to be updated here as it only shows 2.7 here.
http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/python-api
Also the install link seems not updated

Comment: I am not sure who I should contact for that.  I left a comment under Ryan Hamilton's answer above, but he did not respond.  I'll try the "Contact Us" form on the TimeStored web site.

Comment: Dear Alexander, I have been using qPython for the past couple of weeks now, and this is the first time I hear about PyQ. Since speed is a must, I'd love to switch to PyQ. But I have a few questions.

In the doc's I can't seem to find anything on the sub/pub mechanism. Since I have a few callback functions being triggered by a subscription, I'd like to know: is this too possible using PyQ?

Secondly: I'm working with a kdb+ instance inside a docker container. Will this still be possible when switching to PyQ?

Thanks in advance, PyQ looks delicious ;)

Comment: whoops: @AlexanderBelopolsky

Comment: The answer is "yes" to both of your questions. With PyQ, you can use kdb+ pub/sub mechanisms or any of the various Python frameworks.  We've used Python bindings to 0MQ successfully. We use docker for running unit tests under various Linux flavors, so this use is well supported.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the exxeleron qpython library fairly extensively, and have found it to be a nice package for Python <-> kdb+ IPC. Last I recall, it has issues with serialising multibyte characters (at least in Python 2.7) when sending to kdb+, so as a workaround I convert strings/symbols to bytecode and do a `` `$ `` or `` `char$ `` on the kdb+ side.

It's not the fastest thing in the world - its de/serialisation feels a little less fast than it could be (at least in 2.7 - I haven't tested in Python 3) - but it is a friendly interface to kdb+ IPC from Python. It has nice hooks for sub/pub model (using .receive on the connection object), and is relatively well-documented for something kdb+ related (there's even some nice client examples for pub/sub processing!).

I haven't tested with pyQ, which should in theory be better for doing computation-heavy work as it does as much as possible in kdb+ rather than in Python, but for times when you can offload most of your work to a kdb+ process and want to e.g. analyse results or use Python specific packages (e.g. for NLP/ML etc.) qpython works quite well.

Comment: Thanks. Ease of use is definitely of more importance to me than speed. I am playing around with qpython right now and I quite like it